# Unable to find a specification for `React-Core` depended upon by `RNCPicker` 1.6.0 with React Native 0.59

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I was getting this error when running `pod install` for `RNCPicker` of version 1.6.0 with React Native 0.59

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-Core` depended upon by `RNCPicker`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

In my case I have to use these specific versions.
How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React-Core` is outdated and has been renamed to `React`

I have added the following lines to the bottom of my `Podfile` under `ios`.

```
def change_lines_in_file(file_path, &change)
  print "Fixing #{file_path}...\n"
  
  contents = []
  
  file = File.open(file_path, 'r')
  file.each_line do | line |
    contents << line
  end
  file.close
  
  File.open(file_path, 'w') do |f|
    f.puts(change.call(contents))
  end
end

change_lines_in_file('../node_modules/@react-native-community/picker/RNCPicker.podspec') do |lines|
  lines.map { |line| line.include?("s.dependency 'React-Core'") ? "s.dependency 'React'" : line}
end
```

In this way, everytime when I am trying to run `pod install`, it finds my outdated RNCPicker and replace the `React-Core` dependency name to `React`